# how and when to delete old neo4j transaction log files

Tags: neo4j

My local Neo4j has a lot of transaction logs in `data/graph.db`:

```
251M  3 Sep 16:44 neostore.transaction.db.0
255M  3 Sep 20:01 neostore.transaction.db.1
255M  3 Sep 23:20 neostore.transaction.db.2
251M  4 Sep 19:34 neostore.transaction.db.3
250M  4 Sep 22:16 neostore.transaction.db.4
134M  5 Sep 05:02 neostore.transaction.db.5
16B  5 Sep 09:57 neostore.transaction.db.6
16B  7 Sep 16:44 neostore.transaction.db.7
```

I'm backing the `graph.db` folder up (I have stopped the neo4j instance) in order to reload in another offsite instance, so it would be nice to reduce the folder size.

1. What methods are there to control these logs?
2. How do I check if a given `neostore.transaction.db.X` file has been successfully processed?
3. Is it safe to remove older processed files?

Logical logs are referred to in the docs, which I believe are the same files:
http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-logical-logs.html

In `conf/neo4j.properties` I've changed the option `keep_logical_logs` to `100M size`:

```
# Keep logical logs, helps debugging but uses more disk space, enabled for
# legacy reasons To limit space needed to store historical logs use values such
# as: "7 days" or "100M size" instead of "true".
keep_logical_logs=100M size
```

and restarted neo4j, but it hasn't removed any of the old log files.
Can I do this manually when neo4j has stopped? Or are all of these files required?
I stopped neo4j, made a backup of the `graph.db` directory, removed all bar `neostore.transaction.db.7` and started neo4j again. It appears to be happy but...

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you database in good condition you can delete all neostore.transaction.db.x files, but I recommend to you backup them.

1. Stop Neo4j
2. Delete neostore.transaction.db.x files
3. Start Neo4j

Comment: Thanks @MicTech. Do you know of any 'official' info in the neo4j docs re: transaction log files?

Comment: They are used for recovery and online backup, so if you cleanly shut down your database you can delete all. Except if you need to pull backups from that database.

Comment: @MichaelHunger to be clear, if I stop the db, remove the transaction.db files, then start the db. DB continues to be used for some time and then I wish to take a back up, I will not be able to backup? Thanks.

Comment: Do NOT delete all of your transaction files. This will render your setup unusable. The recommended way to lower your transaction files is through the conf file. 
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12084

Comment: This is not a solution - do not manually delete logs - instead use the retention_policy to accomplish similar result

Answer (score 7):

Updating:

In neo4j 3.x, the config has changed to:

```
dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=<true/false>
dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=<amount> <type>
```

see https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/transaction-logs/ for more details

Answer (score 1):

The properties file has a parameter for rotating TX logs:

```
# Will keep logical logs which contains any transaction committed within 2 days
keep_logical_logs=2 days
```

Check the docs for more detailed information on the different options that are available.